# Getting nginx 404 error on uploaded files

Tags: nginx, plesk

I am using PHP (5.3) to upload jpeg files, create folders for those files and store them. I have a development version and a live version both running on the same server (CentOS 7, Apache, Plesk 12).

On the live version, I am experiencing no problems, but on the dev version, the files are uploading successfully but I am getting nginx 404 errors when trying to access them through the browser.

If I try to access something which doesn't exist, I get a standard 404 error (not an nginx one).

When checking the access_log, I see a 200 code for the files.

Nothing in the error_log nor in the nginx error log.

No differences in PHP code, folder structure or configuration.

I recently changed servers and this is the first time I have attempted this upload on the dev system on this new server. Live version is used daily for this activity.

If I try to access older uploads on the dev server, they all work fine. It is only affecting new uploads.

Permissions and ownership are the same for both live and dev systems and old/new folders/files.

If I manually upload a jpeg to the folder, it also triggers an nginx 404 when accessed.

I have no experience with nginx so I am at a loss as to what I can try to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have upload and access files in one place but checking log in another place.

Are you sure you have no issues with domain name resolving?

Also it can be issue with virtual host - when you access file it overtaken by some other virtual host. It maybe default host for IP address.

I recommend you grep all system and vhost logs for file you have trying to access.

Comment: Thanks. I check the virtual hosts and, although the wildcard subdomain alias had been set up in Apache, it wasn't set up in nginx. (however it was for the live system).
Strange that anything worked - and even stranger than older files were working but the newly uploaded ones weren't.